# Custom format using FillExpressions in LiveBinding with ISO8061 DateTime string

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I use an SQLite database to store datetime values. Because SQLite has no type for datetime I use text in ISO8061 string format.

I have a query that represents my fields, I could use the query itself to format the string, but in Delphi Visual components (LinkList) it is possible to manipulate to values before presenting them to the fields. For example there are `StrToDate` and `SubString`. But `StrToDate` says it is not a valid format. And this does not work:

```
SubString(Value,8,2)+"."+SubString(Value,5,2)+"."+SubString(Value,0,4)
```

Any hints for that?

Comment: Are you looking for ``System.DateUtils.DateToISO8601`` or ``ISO8601ToDate``?

Comment: I know this Methods, but they are not available inside the Visual Bindings. Only Methods that are located inside the Tbindinglist --> Methods are available. An, if I See it right, no chance to extend them.

Comment: "*SQLite has no type for datetime*" - true, but it has several ways to store date/times, per the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html): "*SQLite has no DATETIME datatype. Instead, dates and times can be stored in any of these ways: 1) As a TEXT string in the ISO-8601 format. Example: '2018-04-02 12:13:46'. 2) As an INTEGER number of seconds since 1970 (also known as "unix time"). 3) As a REAL value that is the fractional Julian day number.*" And it has [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for working with date/time values.

Comment: `SubString()` is 1-indexed, not 0-indexed. Your indexes are off by 1 position. Also, iI you use the `StrTo(Date|Time)` and `(Date|Time)ToStr()` functions, make sure you use their `TFormatSettings` parameter to specify the formatting you want. The default formatting is based on the OS, not on ISO-8601, which is why you get "invalid" errors.

Comment: Hi Remy, my Question is explizitly for the livebinding. My index is correct. I Tested it, yes it confuses me too. DateToString (do not mix up with DateToStr) can not handle ISO-8601

Comment: For everyone who may have the same Problem. I changed my SQL query to build the needed Strings in its Query and use Visual Binding for only display the Data